# Importing jQuery function to Ember error "i is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to implement the below jQuery calls to be used in my Ember Controller as actions.

jQuery (taken from http://jsfiddle.net/simo/57SR9/94/):

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(){
    for(i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        if(chart.series[i].selected == false){
            chart.series[i].select();
            showSeries.call(chart.series[i], {checked: true});
        }
    }
});
$('#uncheckAll').click(function(){
    for(i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        if(chart.series[i].selected == true){
            chart.series[i].select();
            showSeries.call(chart.series[i], {checked: false});
        }
    }
});
```

Implementation in Ember:

```
checkAll() {
  Ember.$('#checkAll').click(function(){
      for(i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
          if(chart.series[i].selected == false){
              chart.series[i].select();
              showSeries.call(chart.series[i], {checked: true});
          }
      }
  });
},

uncheckAll() {
  Ember.$('#uncheckAll').click(function(){
      for(i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
          if(chart.series[i].selected == true){
              chart.series[i].select();
              showSeries.call(chart.series[i], {checked: false});
          }
      }
  });
},
```

But I'm getting the error: `"i is not defined"` when I click the buttons:

```
  checkAll: function checkAll() {
    _ember['default'].$('#checkAll').click(function () {
      for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) { <== error here
        if (chart.series[i].selected == false) {
          chart.series[i].select();
          showSeries.call(chart.series[i], { checked: true });
        }
      }
    });
  },
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `for (iet  = 0; i < foo; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the variable i. To fix, change your for loops to instead say:

```
for (let i=0; i<chartSeries.length; i++)
```

Comment: yep now the chart is undefined since I don't know how to access the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare variables `var chart` & `var series = chart.series, i;`.
Check your own `jsfiddle` line number 1 & 18.

While converting your `jQuery` code to `Ember`, you forgot to include that.

Include the below code

`var chart;`

`var series = chart.series, i;`